# HttpsURLConnection POST method failing. I don't know if I have the correct writer and/or outputstream writer. For multipart/form-data

Tags: java, post, multipartform-data, content-disposition, httpsurlconnection

I am using multipart/form-data to send a POST request. I used a file that has the data stored as a csv.The file is person,positon,id. I am concerned that the error could be not having the correct writer like Dataoutput stream vs outputstream. The way I have the carriage returns and line feeds setup or any of my connection settings are off. The URL is correct but the last parameter asks for a file name and I put that in content-dispostion. I can't get rid of this error with all the changes I make. I just want to know if anything on this is incorrect. I get back a 500 error but that leads to the received this error:

*org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly*

Any advice or changes would be appreciated.

public static String postFile(String url) throws IOException {

```
      String boundary = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

      String charset = "UTF-8";

      String CRLF = "\r\n";

      int boundaryLength = 181;     

      try {

          BufferedReader in = null;

          File userss = new File("bytesExampleCSV.csv");

          URL obj = new URL(url);

          HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

          conn.setDoOutput(true);

          conn.setDoInput(true);

          conn.setUseCaches(false);

          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

          conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",

                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Mobile Safari/537.36");


          conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf((userss.length()) + boundaryLength));

          conn.connect();

          OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();

          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);

          try {

               writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF);

               writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bytesExampleCSV.csv\"; filename=\""

                         + userss.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);

               writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);

               writer.append(CRLF).flush();

               Files.copy(userss, output);

               output.flush();

               // writer.append(CRLF);

               writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();

               writer.close();

               conn.disconnect();

               System.out.println(output);

          } catch (Exception e) {

               e.printStackTrace();

          }
```

Comment: I see tomcat is throwing error, can you check if this is your case ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597598/multipart-file-upload-using-spring-boot-with-tomcat-version-9-0-31-is-failing

Comment: So I am sending this post to another department, and unfortunately I get a 500 error and contact help desk. When I contact them they send me that error saying it is on my side of code that is causing the issue not theirs.

Comment: I dont know what all libraries you have access to, but root cause will be clear if you can test some upload to same server using some other libraries, like in this post  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java